# C++ Mark for contiguous sections in a 3D array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, recursion, multidimensional-array

If we have a 3x3x3 array of objects, which contain two members: a boolean, and an integer; can anyone suggest an efficient way of marking this array in to contiguous chunks, based on the boolean value.
For example, if we picture it as a Rubix cube, and a middle slice was missing (everything on 1,x,x == false), could we mark the two outer slices as separate groups, by way of a unique group identifier on the int member.

The same needs to apply if the "slice" goes through 90 degrees, leaving an L shape and a strip.

Could it be done with very large 3D arrays using recursion? Could it be threaded.

I've hit the ground typing a few times so far but have ended up in a few dead ends and stack overflows.

Very grateful for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done that way:

```
struct A {int m_i; bool m_b;};
enum {ELimit = 3};
int neighbour_offsets_positive[3] = {1, ELimit, ELimit*ELimit};

A cube[ELimit][ELimit][ELimit];
A * first = &cube[0][0][0];
A * last = &cube[ELimit-1][ELimit-1][ELimit-1];

// Init 'cube'.
for(A * it = first; it <= last; ++it)
    it->m_i = 0, it->m_b = true;

// Slice.
for(int i = 0; i != ELimit; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j != ELimit; ++j)
        cube[1][i][j].m_b = false;

// Assign unique ids to coherent parts.
int id = 0;
for(A * it = first; it <= last; ++it)
{
    if (it->m_b == false)
        continue;
    if (it->m_i == 0)
        it->m_i = ++id;
    for (int k = 0; k != 3; ++k)
    {
        A * neighbour = it + neighbour_offsets_positive[k];
        if (neighbour <= last)
            if (neighbour->m_b == true)
                neighbour->m_i = it->m_i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I'll implement it and see how it goes and report back.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the term "contiguous chunk" correctly, i.e the maximal set of all those array elements for which there is a path from each vertex to all other vertices and they all share the same boolean value, then this is a problem of [finding connected components in a graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) which can be done with a simple [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Imagine that each array element is a vertex, and two vertices are connected if and only if 1) they share the same boolean value 2) they differ only by one coordinate and that difference is 1 by absolute value (i.e. they are adjacent)